# ¿Cómo subir una imagen con PHP al localhost en Linux?

Tags: php, linux, fileupload

Buen día a todos, espero no molestar con mi pregunta.
Estoy intentando guardar una imagen en una carpeta, pero no me deja guardarlo.
Los permisos que tiene mi carpeta son los siguientes:

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

Mi carpeta se llama 'pruebas' y otra carpeta que se llama 'images' (que es donde se almacenarán las imágenes).
Dentro de mi carpeta 'pruebas', tengo un archivo .php que se llama 'imagenCrud.php', y su contenido es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Prueba</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <b>Campo de tipo texto:</b>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="cadenatexto" size="20" maxlength="100">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">
    <br>
    <br>
    <b>Enviar un nuevo archivo: </b>
    <br>
    <input name="userfile" type="file">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="registrar">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['registrar'])) {
    //Recogemos el archivo enviado por el formulario
    $archivo = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    //Si el archivo contiene algo y es diferente de vacio
    if (isset($archivo) && $archivo != "") {
        //Obtenemos algunos datos necesarios sobre el archivo
        $tipo = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
        $tamano = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
        $temp = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        //Se comprueba si el archivo a cargar es correcto observando su extensión y tamaño
        if (!((strpos($tipo, "gif") || strpos($tipo, "jpeg") || strpos($tipo, "jpg") || strpos($tipo, "png")) && ($tamano < 2000000))) {
            echo '<div><b>Error. La extensión o el tamaño de los archivos no es correcta.<br/>
    - Se permiten archivos .gif, .jpg, .png. y de 200 kb como máximo.</b></div>';
        } else {
            //Si la imagen es correcta en tamaño y tipo
            //Se intenta subir al servidor
            if (move_uploaded_file($temp, 'images/' . $archivo)) {
                //Mostramos el mensaje de que se ha subido co éxito
                echo '<div><b>Se ha subido correctamente la imagen.</b></div>';
                //Mostramos la imagen subida
                echo '<p><img src="images/' . $archivo . '"></p>';
            } else {
                //Si no se ha podido subir la imagen, mostramos un mensaje de error
                echo '<div><b>Ocurrió algún error al subir el fichero. No pudo guardarse.</b></div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Técnicamente está bien, pero, al momento de hacer un 'submit', me manda el mensaje de '
Ocurrió algún error al subir el fichero. No pudo guardarse.'
Ya llevo horas averiguando qué estoy haciendo mal.
¿Podrían orientarme en cómo resolverlo, por favor?

Comment: En tu directorio con permisos 755 **solo el  propietario del mismo puede escribir**, el grupo y el resto de usuarios solo pueden leer y ejecutar. No lo mencionas, así que la primera pregunta es quien es el propietario de ese directorio. Para que con esos permisos pueda escribir, el usuario que ejecuta el script tiene que ser el propietario de directorio `imagenes` también.

Comment: Puedes determinar el propietario  con `stat -c "%U" ruta/al/directorio` en una terminal. Por otro lado con `<?php echo \`whoami\`; ?>` desde tu propio php puedes determinar el usuario bajo el que se ejecuta tu php, si se ejecuta bajo un server como apache suele ser www-data, httpd... depende de tu configuración . Si no coinciden, o extiendes los permisos o cambias el propietario del directorio o  el usuario que ejecuta el archivo.

Comment: @FSJevilla , en mi script escribí <?php echo 'whoami'; ?> y me sale este mensaje: daemon

Comment: [daemon](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/usernames.html) es el usuario bajo el que se ejecuta tu script. Supongo que usas apache, el usuario y grupo esta definido en httpd.conf ([directivas User y Group](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_unixd.html#user)).  Puedes cambiar el propietario y grupo del directorio con chown, por ejemplo: `sudo chown -R daemon images`.  Dependiendo de tu sistema y configuración (como SELinux.) puede que no sea tan simple.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolverlo, necesitamos agregar permisos de propietarios, grupos y otros usuarios a la carpeta en la cual se van a almacenar las imágenes. Para explicarlo detalladamente y sea entendible, comencemos.

Tenemos los permisos `drwxr-xr-x,` esto significa lo siguiente:

```
d: directorio
rwx: permisos de lectura, escritura y ejecución.
```

Existen tres tipos de roles:

```
u: usuario
g: grupo
o: otros
a: todos (all), si necesitas aplicar el mismo permiso a usuario, grupos y otros, usa «a» para ahorrar tiempo.
```

Dos tipos de símbolos, que usaremos si la asignación de los permisos se realiza en modo simbólico, para vincular estos a los usuarios se usarán los siguientes símbolos.

```
+: añadir permisos
-: quitar permisos
```

Tres tipos de permisos que podemos asignar a los usuarios.

```
r: lectura
w: escritura
x: ejecución
```

Entonces, dentro de tu proyecto, abres una terminal y ahí comienzas a teclear los permisos a agregar, en este caso escribimos:

```
chmod ugo+rwx images
```

Con esto estamos diciendo que agregaremos permisos a la carpeta `'images'` de lectura, escritura y ejecución al usuaio, grupo y otros.
Luego de agregar estos permisos tecleamos:

```
ls -l
```

y nos aparecerán los permisos que hemos agregado a la carpeta.

```
drwxrwxrwx //Estos son los permisos que nos aparecen en consola al lado de la carpeta.
```

Espero con esto les resuelva el problema que alguno que llegue a tener conflictos en Linux.

Comment: Es importante advertir que establecer los permisos en 777 (rwxrwxrwx) aunque solucione el problema en muchos casos de "lucha contra el sistema de permisos de linux" no es recomendable si no se sabe muy bien que se esta haciendo, especialmente los permisos de others.... Básicamente le estamos dando acceso al directorio/archivo a todo el mundo lo cual puede ser nefasto dependiendo del entorno y contexto. Como norma general, se debe seguir el [principio de mínimo privilegio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_m%C3%ADnimo_privilegio) siempre.

Comment: Nota que solamente se está dando permiso a la carpeta, y no a toda la aplicación.